# Neither Spring Security Default Login page not rendering nor able to create custom login page

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new in spring security and configuring this following these [1](http://sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa-springsecurity-configuration-using-javaconfig/) [2](http://websystique.com/springmvc/springmvc-hibernate-many-to-many-example-annotation-using-join-table/) links-

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` Implementaion-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
        registry.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

      @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/login/form**","/register","/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin","/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login/form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login/form?error")
            .permitAll();
      }
}
```

`UserDetailsService` Implemtation

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(userName);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName "+userName+" not found");
        }
        return new SecurityUser(user);
    }
}
```

`User` Implementation-

```
public class SecurityUser extends User implements UserDetails
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public SecurityUser(User user) {
        if(user != null)
        {
            this.setId(user.getId());
            this.setName(user.getName());
            this.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            this.setDob(user.getDob());
            this.setRoles(user.getRoles());
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Role> userRoles = this.getRoles();

        if(userRoles != null)
        {
            for (Role role : userRoles) {
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName());
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

And my `SpringWebAppInitializer` class is-

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] {  AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class};
    }



    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
       return new Filter[]{ 
               new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"),
               new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    } 

}
```

My problem is - How can I register this user to spring security?Is there any default controller for this?If yes what is its url?

```
<form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="${appUrl}/controller/login"
                    modelAttribute="user" class="register" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                                class="form-control register-input" placeholder="UserName" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                class="form-control register-input" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Comment: No there isn't... Spring Security is only about securing your app, not about user management.

Comment: @M.Deinum so how can we register our user to Spring security

Comment: what i am missing ie what code should i write in my controller to make my user in spring acknowledgement,that this user is currently logged in.

Comment: Create a form, controller and register it yourself.

Comment: Do you want to register a user, i.e create a new user or do you simply want to login?! That is completely unclear to me now.

Comment: I want to login not register,i have role,user,and userrole domain with data.

Comment: I believe on every request spring-security authenticate user on the basis of his  role,so how does spring-security get to know, which user is actually need to be authenticate?also is this in our database or not?

Comment: That isn't registering... Spring Security does that for you, you don't need a controller...

Comment: my question is spring-security authenticate user on the basis of his role,so how does spring-security get to know, which user is actually need to be authenticate?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong it authenticates on username not role... Instead of guessing I suggest a read of the spring security guide and take a look at a simple sample.

Comment: exactly it authenticates on username not role.but which user.
Acutually i am not getting any login form from spring side.moreover when we create our own custom login form,spring security is unable to know ie we are not able to make it in springsecurities acknowledgement.

Comment: You can make whatever form , just make sure you include the prop username/password fields. As stated read the manual and look at a basic sample.

Comment: what would be action of this form?

Comment: What you specified for the `loginProcessingUrl`... But all that is explained in the manual...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a controller, Spring Security uses servlet filters to handle logging in and out (this lets it work with applications that don't use Spring MVC). The logic is in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and the default login URL is `/login` (POST). It's usual, but not necessary, to have a GET controller at `/login` that displays the form.